Where can we download com_jupgrade extension for upgrading Joomla 1.5.15 to 1.5.26?
We plan to upgrade our online shop with Virturalmart to new Joomla 4.x or 5.x, but we need to upgrade to Joomla 1.5.26. However, we can not find Matware.com.ar or Google for download the following files:
com_jupgrade-0.5.2.zip
com_jupgrade-1.2.4.zip
We would be appreciated if someone can inform us the link for download the files.
Thanks a lot!

You don't need jUpgrade to update Joomla from Joomla 1.5.15 to Joomla 1.5.26 as the core Joomla Update component can do this.
Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be any reputable link to jUpgrade any more.
jMigrator from DayCounts plus the VirtueMart Addon is probably the best option when migrating Joomla and VirtueMart from Joomla 1.5 to a later version.

The Joomla 1.5.26 update is done. But, the front page is Joomla installation page (not our original page), any update for some files for fixing this problem?

Have you seen the download link https://downloads.joomla.org/fr/cms/joomla15/1-5-26

You are the help star!
We download the Joomla 1.5.0 to 1.5.26 Patch file and copy all file in the  directory \htdocs, it is successful to upgrade to Joomla 1.5.26.
However, we found out that the front page change to Joomla page instead of the original page (it displays Joomla page when we click the Home Page).
Please advise us whether we need to have some configuation for fixing this problem.
Thanks a lot!

@TrendAudio, this 'post' doesn't meet the question and answer nature of Joomla Stack Exchange that is different from other discussion style help Forums and as such has been down voted by members of JSE as it is not Answer.  "You are the help star" is not required and should be replaced by accepting the Answer that helped you, that in turns rewards the person with points. "We Download..." is good elaboration however it should be a comment of the accepted answer to help future readers understand what you did to resolve your issue.

It can take some reading of existing posts to get feel for things and maybe read some of the help pages on how things are done differently on Stack Exchange but generally each Question should be about one specific issue you are having. To this end the rest of your post/answer should be created in a new Question asking about how to resolve your new issue with the Home page not displaying correctly. The nature of Stack Exchange is about not only helping you now but helping other people in the future with the same or similar issue finding the 'correct' answer in a timely manner.

Accepting an answer not only shows appreciation and builds the reputation of the person whom has taken the time to understand your issue and provide an answer but it also builds your own reputation as someone that follows through on their question and will tend to garner more help in the future. If you solve your issue yourself you can/should follow up with an Answer explaining what you did or the cause of the issue and you can accept your own Answer, again adding to your reputation.
